# LocalNotifications Issues in Android tablets and iPad devices

Tags: codenameone

I am working on developing an app for Android & IOS devices. I am getting local notifications in Mobile devices (Both Android & IOS) and the same not working in Android tablets and iPad devices. Below is the code snippet for your reference.

```
        LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
        n.setId("demo-notification");
        n.setAlertBody(records.toString());
        n.setAlertTitle("Break Time!");
        Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(n,
        System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000, // fire date/time
        LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE  // Whether to repeat and what frequency
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you provided details about which versions of iOS and Android you're experiencing this on.  At least on iOS, local notifications will only be delivered when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `System.currentTimeMillis()` as this is implied in the scheduling that it will be in the future...

Comment: Tried by removing the System.currentTimeMillis().  If I remove that, we are not getting any alerts. As I said in my earlier message I am getting this problem only with Android tablets.

Comment: FYI you need to answer to Steve otherwise he doesn't get an alert. You also wrote in the question "and ipad" which makes it seem like the issue is happening both on iOS and Android. It's also unclear how the issue manifests itself exactly.